# Android ant build loses packaged Ormma JavaScript files after upgrade to ADT r14

Tags: android, build

I have several .jar files included in a library project that are required for ads to work in my main application. One of those is the Ormma.jar. The Ormma.jar includes two JavaScript objects, ormma.js and ormma_bridge.js. We upgraded our build environment to use the new Android Tools
revision 14 (http://developer.android.com/sdk/tools-notes.html) and
when we do a build now the ormma.js and ormma_bridge.js files are not
included in the built Android .apk.

Any idea why this is happening? I see logs from my build stating that
Android is copying the ormma.jar to the correct library, just like
before, but when I unzip the apk the normal js folder is missing
(Along with those JavaScript files). We have other .jar files that do not include JavaScript
objects and they appear to work fine. Any and all suggestions are welcome. I tried posting my build.xml but it kept giving me issues. I will try to get it in here. Thanks!

Jared

Build.xml - It is def not letting me add my full build.xml so I will add the important piece - Our Mak call: aim:@ant CM_MAKE_VER=1.8.2 -f build.xml aol-release

```
        <target name="aol-release" depends="set-version, disable-debug, release">

        <!-- Use the CM script presumably to protect key/keystore passwords from... ninjas? -->
        <!-- Is this worth external dependency? It would be easy to use jarsigner and maintain our own key. -->

        <exec executable="perl" failonerror="true">
            <arg value="/cm/sys/admin/sign"/>
            <arg value="apk"/>
            <arg value="android" />
            <!-- The CM script does not rename and requires a relative path.
                 Default Android packaging targets also use ant.project.name vs. out.* properties. -->
            <arg value="aim/bin/${ant.project.name}-release-unsigned.apk"/>
        </exec>

        <!--  <zipalign in.package="${out.unsigned.package}" out.package="${out.release.package}" />-->
        <zipalign-helper in.package="${out.unsigned.package}" out.package="${out.release.package}" />

        <!-- We now have only aligned debug and release packages. -->
        <delete file="${out.unsigned.package}"/>

    </target>
```